# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'version' gensim

Tags: linux, python-3.x

После кода

```
wv_embeddings = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/kostya/natural-language-processing/week3/data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',binary=True)
```

Результат:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'version'

Я не знаю, почему. Прошу помощи.

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: У вас метод где-то ожидает **число в строковом представлении**, а вы ему подсовываете **строку** *version*.